# when i set title in componentDidMount, how can i get title in server side?

Tags: reactjs, server, rendering

I want to know how you set the title of each page with ReactJS

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a state variable as for the title in the render method (Or a Prop, if you use Redux)

```
<title>{this.state.pageTitle}</title>
```

And the value should be set in the componentDidMount() (I believe you already have code to retrieve the title from the db to something like like pageDataStore.title . pageDataStore is the imaginary data store)

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.setState({pageTitle: pageDataStore.title})
}
```